# How can I retrieve correct credentials to access AWS SecretsManger on a boto3 client using AWS Cognito - Indentity Pool

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to retrieve AWS Secret (which is boto3 config) using a standalone application running python3 (kivy).

The client uses boto3 and works fine with a the credentials hard coded in.

I'm trying to get the creds using `get_credentials_for_identity` in boto3.

I've created a federation identity pool and assigned a policy for it to access secrets manager:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "Resource": "<arn-of-the-secret-the-app-needs-to-access>"
    }
}
```

I've also done the same using generic Cognito role. (Knowing this isn't the issue but I'm sure we all do dumb *hit trying to solve something).

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name='eu-west-1')
response = client.get_credentials_for_identity(
    #identity taken from fedenration/identity pools;app with cognito access
    IdentityId='eu-west-1:6###...',
)
creds_dic = response['Credentials']
awsaccesskey = creds_dic['AccessKeyId']
awsseckey = creds_dic['SecretKey']
print(response)
print(awsseckey)
print(awsaccesskey)
```

gives me the wrong `AccessKeyId` and `SecretKey` the ones it provides I can't even find. I think I'm asking for the access key/secret for the IAM that is holding this `identity` but I need the access key/secret for the IAM role which is accesing the `secrets manager` so I can feed them in to boto3 and retrieve the creds/secret.

I also need the same for `user pool` but can configure that out once I realise the stupidity I'm doing.

Comment: The credentials you are getting are most likely are the temporary credentials generated for the session using IAM Role. Question is, have you tried using the retrieved credentials in boto3 to get the secrets?.

Comment: Yes! That's where I'm getting my `invalid token error` - I get_credentials_for_identity using my indentity pool which has permissions for `secretsmanager` I pass these through my `SecretsManager` and get invalid token

Answer (score 0):

Cognito generates new credentials which are vended by AWS STS. You would not be able to match those credentials with the existing IAM generated credentials you have. To access AWS Secrets Manager APIs, ensure that your Cognito Identity Pool's `Authenticated Role` has the adequate permissions.

Comment: My `Authenticated role` and my `unAuthenticated` roles have the correct permissions.

I'm using the following policy `SecretsManagerReadWrite`.

I'm still getting an invalid token error. 

`response_getcreds = client.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId='eu-west-1:fbfda46a-0e03-4aa4-bf54-049467ccbfb3',)`

Comment: It won't be invalid. Try using the generates creds via the AWS CLI as a test.

Comment: my `IdentityId` is being generated from `GetId` when I use my `identity pool` 's pool id... It feels like my permissions are wrong somewhere. I've even allocated AdminAccess to my `unathen` role which being used in both. I'll try the CLI method now!

Comment: Using `aws cli` and the creds generated from `get_credentials_for_identity` gives me the same token error

Comment: Do I need to specfiy `Trusted entities` ? I currently only have `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com `

Comment: Also do I need two seperate roles for `auth` and `unauth` or can I just use the one with the required permissions?

Comment: You need two separate roles. Test via the CLI first, using the Identity Pool API calls(GetID and GetCredentialsForIdentity).

Comment: STS will assume the Auth role if a Logins Map is provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192599/discussion-between-cl0ud-l3ss-and-arka-mukherjee).